# Confused on Updating Table using DataGrid

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

[image]

-Image on top Codes Below....

```
private void Save_FGARec()
{            
    try
    {                
        for(int x= 0; x < FGAdataGrid.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            sysSFCDBDataContext SFC = new sysSFCDBDataContext();
            Sales_FGAllocated FGA = SFC.Sales_FGAllocateds.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowID == Convert.ToInt64(FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value));
            if (FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value != null)
            {                         
                FGA.TotalLoaded = Convert.ToInt64(FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[6].Value);
                SFC.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else 
            {
                SFC.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }                
}
```

-- Is my Code on Update Right? I'm confuse coz my table doesn't update what i store on this column totalloaded which counts as cell[8]... did i missed something here?

Comment: have you debug and check, is it come to `SFC.SubmitChanges` line and you have set `TotalLoaded` value before that?

Comment: Yes i did.. the debug flow goes smoothly no errors.. i runs all the flow but then later i check my table no updates.. i use same code on my other form works well but not on this one.. although it was a bit different on the other form i never use any forloop unlike this one due to the datagrid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below, not sure this will solve the issue, but may be you are not dispose/ close the data context correctly with current code. you can use `using` block like below

```
using (sysSFCDBDataContext SFC = new sysSFCDBDataContext())
{
    Sales_FGAllocated FGA = SFC.Sales_FGAllocateds.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RowID == Convert.ToInt64(FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value));

    if (FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value != null)
    {
        FGA.TotalLoaded = Convert.ToInt64(FGAdataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[6].Value);
        SFC.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still not changing... i dunno why... is it because of the for loop? but i check its datagrid values each time it loops it changes row it goes by the flow no errors i don't understand why it does not update on the table... i even check the rowID which is a Bigint so it right to convert the datagrid value to int64 which is long.. right..

Comment: What is the primary key of this `Sales_FGAllocateds`? can you check the value you get when you debug for primary key? and also you can check the generated SQL when you call `SubmitChanges` by using `SFC.Log`

Comment: I see.. now it updates.. i never place any primary key then at the tables that explains.. big thank you for the help sir...